# Actor appearing in ITV (Uk tv) 118-118 ident

Tags: identify-this-actor

As part of ITV (1-4) film sponsorship, 118-118 use various humorous shorts before and after advert breaks.

One of these has the 2 mustachioed regulars asking a third character (this third actors footage comes from another, unknown to me, programme) "where did you get that shirt?" - he answers, something like, Ziggys.

I'm sure users in the UK will be very familiar with this advert/ident. If I was more computer literate I'd post a picture, but I'm not. If someone who knows how to (probably most of you) please post a picture to help answer this enquiry.

Anyway, my question is 'Is the guy in the horrendous shirt Jonathan Frakes (of Star Trek TNG)?'

The ad is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S3IPRVJUBpg), and here's his picture.

[image]

Comment: Added the ad. Doubt it's Frakes, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for popping the picture up, Im really undecided, hoping one of the knowledgeable regulars could provide definitive answer. Sometimes I see it (and it's on a lot) and I'm certain it's him, and then I watch a TNG episode and laugh at myself for thinking such rubbish.

Comment: That's definitely not Frakes, I'm still looking into it but based on the quality of the clip and his clothes I'd say it's from a 70s movie.

Comment: Yeah, it does all seem circa 70's, but imagine Frakes a bit older, after a weekend on the booze and...  well, maybe. But the clip could be more recent, many shows have retro, nostalgia episodes/segments etc.

Comment: No idea who it is sorry but I just thought you might be interested to know that those shorts before and after the advertisement window are technically called 'Interstitials' but are referred to as 'Bumpers' by most in the industry.

Comment: @Chopper3 - and the knowledge keeps flowing, thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I [tweeted @118118](https://twitter.com/Crow_T_Lorebot/status/489450599109636096) and they were kind enough to answer for me! The actor is [Russ Tamblyn](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0848560/) in [Black Heat (1976)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0125015/):

[image: From the horse's mouth]

His character name is *Ziggy* as he says in the clip, and searching for it on Google images provided plenty of other shots of him in the same awful shirt so I think that's the one:

[image: Terrible shirt]

Comment: Wow! Thanks for that, although I'm a little disappointed that once again my instincts are wrong it feels even better that another one of those nagging irritations is resolved. Thank you all

Comment: Ok so I applaud you for thinking to ask the source. Brilliant move. I am irritated though that a search on IMDB itself doesn't bring up Russ Tamblyn if you search for Ziggy. Amber Tamblyn's dad y'all.

Comment: @KevinHowell Yeah it's weird, the only thing I could guess is that somehow their character search only includes characters who have a page of appearances on their own and Ziggy is just a one-off character in a B-movie.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the video is not playing (but I do see him in the still before you press the play button), so all I get is audio. The voice sounds a lot like [Patrick Wayne](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0915618/) (John Wayne's son), but I don't ever remember him being on Star Trek, so there's that. The still even looks like him, of what I can see around the large ">" YouTube play button.

Comment: I'll put up a still as well.

Comment: Similarities around the eyes. The actor in question though wasn't necessarily in Star Trek. I've tagged it Star Trek because of the possible (I think) Frakes link. I thought doing so might get the attention of a few Trekkies, and their immense knowledge of all things connected to the show. The actors name would be interesting to know, but of primary importance is whether, or not, this is Frakes.

Comment: @queeg ... Definitely not Frakes. His voice is much deeper. What I could see of your actor, the voice, nose, ear lobes, and brow could easily be Patrick Wayne's. Just when the big "play" botton hogs the rest of his face ... well, you get the picture, lol.